# ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to run a .war file with tomcat on a server. Everytime I startup tomcat it should set a timer, which runs the init()-method of the .war file once in a week. I'm doing this with the CronTrigger from Quartz. The JobBuilder calls the class HelloJob, in which (when running) a huge excel table gets created.

```
public class CronTrigger implements Servlet

{    
    public void init(ServletConfig arg0) throws ServletException {

        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class).withIdentity("Batch Validation Trigger", "group1").build();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("Batch Validation Trigger", "group1").withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 45 14 ? * TUE")).build();
        Logger root = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(CronTrigger.class);
        root.isDebugEnabled();
        //schedule it
        Scheduler scheduler = null;
        try {
            scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            scheduler.start();
        } catch (SchedulerException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        } catch (SchedulerException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>WOQC</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
      <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CronTrigger</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>timer.CronTrigger</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CronTrigger</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When I try to run it, it returns one error and one exception:
NoClassDefFoundError:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at timer.CronTrigger.init(CronTrigger.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        ... 13 more
```

ClassNotFoundException:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /WO threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at timer.CronTrigger.init(CronTrigger.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I already have read the questions about this exception and added slf4j-nop-1.7.7.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar to the classpath. I know that the problem belongs to the implementation of the LoggerFactory, but I couldn't find a good example to solve my problem. If you have any idea, please respond.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so these jars are in WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: Well that was easier than I expected. Had the jars in the wrong library. Moved them to WEB-INF/lib now it's working. Thanks for the fast respond and your help!

Comment: You can answer your own question, just put in what you did for the fix and accept your own answer. This will help folks with similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClassNotFoundException prompts when third party libraries are not identified by the IDE itself. You should add you jars files (third party libraries) into **WEB-INF/lib** folder. Now it should function properly.

Answer (score 0):

add your slf4j.jar in lib directory.

War file structure is as follows

```
WebContent
    --- WEB-INF
         ----web.xml (Deployment Descriptor)
         ---- lib 
                --- Add your libraries here i.e. slf4j*.jar and others
```